# Django ldap authentication without a database model

Tags: django, mongodb, authentication, ldap

I have the following setup:

- django
- mongoDB database via monogengine
- authentication agains LDAP

When trying to implement the authentication i get the following error when `login(request,user)`:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

This is imho the result of django trying to create the User model in the database, which fails, because i don't use a DB model by django itself (instead I use mongoengine)

Here the database setup:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
   }
}

from mongoengine import *
connect('myDB',)
```

Any idea how to use the authentication in that case? Or is there no possibilty to use the django auth mechanism without a django database model?

Answer (score 0):

I think a go-through of following steps for setting up mongoengine will solve your problem-

1) [make django forget your databases](http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine/#/15)

2) [connect to mongoDB](http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine/#/16)

3) [Use MongoEngine's User](http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine/#/17)

4) [Hack the test runner](http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine/#/18)

Hope it helps.